# How to find and merge files in unix

Tags: xml, unix, merge

how to merge various files in `Unix` based on `find` command such that merged files present in their respective directory.

```
a1 - a1_1.xml , a1_2.xml --> full_a1.xml
b1 - b1_1.xml , b1_2.xml --> full_b1.xml
```

Here, `a1` and `b1` are directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this:

```
DIRS=("a1" "b1")
PATT="*.xml"
for dir in "${DIRS[@]}"
do
    find "$dir" -name "$PATT" -exec cat {} > "$(pwd)/$dir/final_xml" \;
done
```

EDIT:

```
for dir in $(find . -type d)
do
    if [[ "$dir" == "." || "$dir" == ".." ]]; then
        continue
    fi

    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 cat > "$dir/final_xml"
done
```

Comment: it is creating only one file...
i want to have two different file in both directories

Comment: If i directly give directory path in for loop will it work because the no. Of directories may increase

Comment: if directory name keeps on changing along with their no., but inside content name remain .xml file then how to do processing of such directories

Comment: @sunnyrajpal, Updated answer.

Comment: a little help, if you can explain 
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 cat > "$dir/final_xml"

new to shell script thats why...

Comment: @sunnyrajpal, Here, `find` will find the files based on the given options, then print the output (filenames) as null terminated. `find`s output will be passed to  `xargs` using pipe(`|`). Now `xargs` split the file names using null separator and forms the argument list to `cat`. `cat` concatenate all the files to output will be redirected to `> filename`. Also refer `man <command>` for more details.

Comment: hi sat, i found a little bug in the final merged file, the content in final file is not in order, i want the all file to be merged in order of their last modified date. let me know if its possible

Comment: @sunnyrajpal, You can try this : `ls -1t "$dir/"*.xml | xargs cat > "$dir/final_xml"`

Comment: @sunnyrajpal, Execute this command `ls -1t *.xml` under XML directory and check whether you are getting XML files in order. (OR) Try : `ls -1rt *.xml`. Here, `-1 (one)` is an option.

Comment: the files are getting in order using the above command but while merging not merged in proper order.